# Trigonometry, $\tan \theta=−6.2319$ and $\cos x=-0.3178$ difference?

Tags: trigonometry

> Given that $\tan \theta= −6.2319$, determine the values of $\theta$ if $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.

Hi, I'm having some trouble trying to understand why in one of the steps of the solution, they needed to switch from $-6.2319$ to $6.2319$.

Here is the supposed answer:

1. Tangent is negative in the 2nd and 4th quadrants.
2. Calculate related acute angle to four decimal places. $$\tan \beta=6.2319 \\ \beta=\tan^{-1}(6.2319) \\ \beta=1.4117$$
3. Use  $\beta$  to calculate  $\theta$ to three decimal places.

$$\theta_1=π−\beta \\ \theta1=π−1.4117 \\ \theta_1=1.730$$

$$\theta_2=2π−\beta  \\ \theta_2=2π−1.4117  \\ \theta_2=4.871$$

Ok, I assumed that the related acute angle is always positive because $\tan^{-1}(-6.2319)$ simply makes $1.4117$ negative, i.e. $-1.4117$.

Then comes a similar question.

> Determine the values of $\theta$ if $0 \leq \theta \leq 2π$ given that $\cos x = − 0.3178$.

I noticed there's an $x$ beside $\cos$, instead of $\theta$... What does this mean? What is $x$?

I tried solving it:

1. Cosine is negative is in 2nd and 3rd quadrants.
2. To four decimal places, $$x = \cos^{-1}(-0.3178)\\ x = 1.8942$$  I have no idea what this number represents, is this related acute angle? Is this principal angle? So I tried positive instead:
   $$x = \cos^{-1}(0.3178)\\ x = 1.2474$$... It's completely different of a number... What? I don't get it, which is principal, which is related acute angle. I'm stuck here, because if it's principal angle, I don't need to do the 3rd step, and if it is related acute angle, I will need to do the third step.

Comment: Variables are placeholders. You can call the angle $x, y, z, \theta, \psi$, whatever.

Comment: -rad is not the same as +rad.

Comment: Determining $\theta$ from $\cos x = \ldots$, maybe the question has a typo.

Comment: Your $x=\cos^{-1}(-0.3178) = 1.8942\ldots$ is an angle in the 2nd quadrant, where $\cos$ is negative. Your $\cos^{-1}(0.3178) = 1.2474\ldots$ is an angle in the 1st quadrant, where $\cos$ is positive. They add up to $\pi$.

Comment: Can you tell me why does - or + sign affect the angle's quadrant? CAST, but cosine is positive in 4th quadrant also, and negative in 3rd quadrant also, why only 2nd and 1st is covered?

Comment: You may refer to the unit circle definition of cosine and sine, where $\cos\theta$ is the $x$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle. Going backward, given a $\cos \theta$, which is an x value, there could be two possible $\theta$s in one turn ($0\le \theta< 2\pi$), and even more when considering all real $\theta$. By convention, the principle value $\cos^{-1} x$ is chosen to be $0\le \cos^{-1}x\le \pi$, either in the 1st or 2nd quadrant or their endpoints.

Comment: Ok I see! But what about sin^-1? 1st quadrant is All, 2nd quadrant is Sine, Sine covers both 1st and 2nd quadrant, so does that means that sin^-1 can only be done to positive numbers? So sin^1 (-1.232) gives error?

Edit: ok, I just tried using calculator sin^1 (-1.234) and it gave error. this confirms it then.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the $\sin^{-1}$ of a negative $y$ within the domain, $-1 \le y < 0$? Using a similar definition, $\sin\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of the same point on the unit circle. There can be also up to two $\theta$s within a turn, given a $y=\sin \theta$. The principal value of $\sin^{-1}y$ is chosen to be in the 1st and 4th quadrants: $-\frac\pi2 \le \sin^{-1}y \le \frac\pi2$.

Comment: Oh, I see, sin^1 does work between -1 and 0, it's the only part of the y-axis of the sine graph where it is negative. Though I don't understand why sinθ is considered y-coordinate, and cosθ is considered x-coordinate.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the history of their definitions. $\sin\theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypothenuse}}$, $\cos\theta = \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypothenuse}}$. In a unit circle, the hypothenuse is $1$, and $\theta$ is measured anticlockwise from the positive $x$-axis, then the opposite side is the $y$-coordinate and the adjacent side is the $x$-coordinate.

Comment: In the first problem, if you did not change the sign to make the arc tangent return a positive angle, then you would just need to **add** the arc tangent angle to $\pi$ and $2\pi$ instead of subtracting it. I think the rationale behind the given solution is that they just make a habit to convert everything to first quadrant to do the trig functions and then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

- I think this is a typo on the book's part - they meant to use $\theta$ instead of $x$.  The usual convention is that $\theta$ will represent degrees and $x$ will represent radians, but other books will switch that convention around.
- You found the principal angle of $1.2474$, but since negative in the second and third quadrants, you would subtract $\pi$ from this answer to get $1.8942$. Since there are two angles that satisfy $\arccos -0.3178$, you would do the same thing as you did for the tangent.  i.e. subtract $2 \pi$ from $1.8942$ to get the other angle, which is $4.3890.$